# Get "Blocked File Types" list from SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Is there any way to request the list of "Blocked File Types" from code?

Optional: And possibly add new items to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the blocked file extensions using the SPWebApplication object and the BlockedFileExtensions property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.blockedfileextensions.aspx

Comment: Excellent! (code used SPContext.Current.Web.Site.WebApplication.BlockedFileExtensions)

Comment: Can the Sharepoint client get this list of Blocked File Extension lists ?